# What's the Dr. Memory's equivalent of the valgrind's "track origins"?

Tags: debugging, dr-memory

In valgrind I turn on `--track-origins` to find out where does the uninitialized value comes from.

On Windows I'm using Dr. Memory, because valgrind isn't ported yet as far as I know. It reports uninitialized reads, but looking at the manual I don't seem to find an option let it find out the origin of the uninitialized value. But it tells me which memory range is offending.

- So does anyone know an option that enables the tracking of origins (which I overlooked)?
- If there is no such option, then having the offending memory range is it possible to find out who allocated it?